# `.controlSize()` not working after using custom ButtonStyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to custom some button styles. But after applying them, the `.controlSize()` modifier will stop working, as shown in below screenshot. Is it possible to support `.controlSize()` in custom `ButtonStyle` or some approaches else can bring this control size back?

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Hello World") { }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .controlSize(.regular)
            
            Button("Hello World") { }
                .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
                .controlSize(.regular)
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(Color.cyan)
            .border(Color.brown)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

You can check the `controlSize` environment value in your custom style and adjust accordingly. For example:

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    @Environment(\.controlSize) var controlSize

    // Ideally switch over every value and produce different styles
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(controlSize == .large ? .title : .body)
            .background(Color.cyan)
            .border(Color.brown)
    }
}
```